# Adding text with Tick Box in a single cell in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

Is it possible to have a Tick Box followed by some text in a cell in google sheets?
I was able to add the Tick Box but when I add a text along with it, it shows a validation error:
[image]

Comment: It is not possible.

Comment: Is there an alternative to it? The aim is to have an item and a checkbox against it. One way would be to use 2 cells. Any other ways?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to change the value of TRUE/FALSE for any tickbox by using the 'Use custom cell values' option in data validation, however this will only change the value seen in the formula bar; in the cell itself it will just be the usual tick or empty box that is seen.

You could potentially create a dropdown with the two options being '✔️ text' and '✖️ text' but I strongly suspect that there's a bit of an XY problem going on in your description, and that the best option is simply to have a column of tickboxes next to a column of text.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear to me as to what would be your use of the text. In any case.
As an alternative you could add a `Note`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to achieve a visual change on the text (e.g. crossing it out when the checkbox is checked) just use two separate columns with conditional formatting based on the value of the checkbox cell. See [my example.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15cni9PsvPlXRr5pih_epHfA8U9jVfl5nZFOI1EqTLV0)

The conditional formatting rule is:

Custom Formula Is

```
=$A2
```

Where A2 is the top cell in the range with checkboxes.

This produces a result like this:

[image]